# FFmpeg - give video padding but only portrait view not horizontal

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to add padding to videos when i merge them so they don't stretch.

its working fine when the video is in portrait mode but when i change it to landscape on mobile device, the video becomes cropped inside of black bars,

my command is

`stringBuilder.append("[$i:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=720:1280:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=720:1280:(720-iw*min(720/iw\\,1280/ih))/2:(1280-ih*min(720/iw\\,1280/ih))/2,setsar=1,setdar=9/16[v$i]; [$i:a]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a$i];")`

**Result as now**

[video in portrait after  vertical padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQqdm.png)

[and here its showing cropped inside, when device is in landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fP1d.png)

Comment: From your screenshots it is not possible to tell where your device/player adds padding and where ffmpeg added padding (you can change pad color with `color` option in pad), but this behavior seems expected to me. You have landscape input. You turn it into portrait output by scaling and adding large letterboxing. When played in device it add pillarbox to fit within view area. What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: what i want is if 1st video is potrait (made from phone camera) , and other video is in landscape some random video , so it adds padding at top and bottom of landscape video. to make it viewable when device is in portrait mode, but when i rotate my device to landscape, my video get padding form all 4 sides . its center inside, pls view the 2nd screenshot, what i want is when device is in landscape the video should not be cropped from all corners instead fit in screen

Comment: The device should automatically and properly show a landscape video while the device is in portrait position. You shouldn't have to add any padding.